# How to remove or modify currency list form PayPal?

Tags: paypal, currency

Is it possible to modify the currency list in PayPal. I would like remove some currencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of currencies in Pay Pal. See the currencies here:  https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/dmo/demo_mc_1-outside . One can accept/pay in more than one currency.

The way to cancel or to stop using one of your currencies (or to make a currency disappear, if you wish) is to click on the "Currency converter" link (on the right to your main balance figure/number (where the amount of money you have on your Pay Pal account is written) - and that will take you to a page with your available active currencies, there select one and deactivate.

Answer (score -1):

There's no 'currency list' in PayPal.